# Receiving null value on sending data from Activity to the fragment withing that Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here is my code of first fragment that is sending Data to the Activity, It is working:

```
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Place:"+place.getLatLng());
            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
            double latitude = latLng.latitude;
            double longitude = latLng.longitude;
            Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Activity_home.class);
            intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
            intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.i(TAG,"An error occured:" + status);
        }
    });
```

Here is the Activity that is receiving the data from fragment and then sending it to 2nd fragment within it:

```
public class Activity_home extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    Toolbar toolbar;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);



        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //floatingActionButton= (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Test App");


        /***************HEADER LAYOUT contents*****************/

        View nav_view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        ImageView profile_img = (ImageView)nav_view.findViewById(R.id.imgProfile_drawer);
        TextView title = (TextView)nav_view.findViewById(R.id.textView_navHeader_name);
        TextView email = (TextView)nav_view.findViewById(R.id.textView_navHeader_email);

        profile_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile_reg);
        title.setText("Moin Hashmi");
        email.setText("moin.hashmi20@gmail.com");

        /***************NAVIGATION DRAWER**********************/

       /* floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });*/

        ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_open,R.string.navigation_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        //Double lonlat = (getIntent().getDoubleExtra("place",0));
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
            double latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude",0.00);
            double longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude",0.00);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

            bundle.putDouble("lat",latitude);
            bundle.putDouble("lon",longitude);
     //            bundle.putString("latitude", latitude+"");
    //            bundle.putString("longitude", longitude+"");


            Fragment fragment = new Map();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_home,fragment).commit();
        }
```

Here is the fragment code that is receiving data from parent Activity:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if(getArguments()!=null) {
        longitude = this.getArguments().getDouble("lon");
        latitude = this.getArguments().getDouble("lat");
    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.gmaps);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    btn_bookNow=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Booknow);
    btn_schedule=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_scheduleLater);

    btn_bookNow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

//              Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapSearch.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
  });

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same key names at both places either **"lat" & "lon"** OR  **"latitude" & "longitude"**.

This is what you have:

```
bundle.putDouble("lat",latitude);
bundle.putDouble("lon",longitude);
```

Check again

```
if(getArguments()!=null) {
    longitude = this.getArguments().getDouble("longitude");
    latitude = this.getArguments().getDouble("latitude");
}
```

I'd also suggest not putting a MapFragment inside another Fragment, but that is a separate issue

Comment: I did check but on setting Debugger mode it shows that getArgument() has null value. It means that if condition is getting false. I don't know why

Comment: You called setArguments, so that shouldn't be null. The values you get from missing keys are null